# how to pass parameters in url without showing in url in playframework

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-2.11

In my Controller i have two Actions `ActionA` and `ActionB` ,In `ActionA` i have a string which i want to send to `ActionB` for that i am doing it like this

```
 object MyController extends Controller {

    def ActionA= Action {
       var str="abc"
          Redirect(controllers.routes.MyController.ActionB(str))
      }

    def signupProcessing1(token:String)= Action {
        Ok("string is " + token)   
      } 
    }
```

in the route file

```
GET    /user/actionB controllers.MyController.ActionB(token:String)  

GET   /user/actionA  controllers.MyUserController.ActionA
```

when i hit `localhost:9000/user/actionA` in browser 
its redirected to this url

```
localhost:9000/user/actionB?token="abc"
```

i do not want to show this string "abc" in the url for that i used `POST` instead of `GET`

```
POST    /user/actionB controllers.MyController.ActionB(token:String)  

GET   /user/actionA  controllers.MyController.ActionA
```

But it gives Exception

```
`Action not found` 

    For request 'GET /user/actionB?token=abc'
```

Please help me how can i pass parameters from one Action to another without showing in the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTP specification for redirect is not meant to change the method from GET to POST.

But there are a few things you can do to solve your problem.

The simplest approach is to not Redirect, just forward to your action:

```
  def ActionA = {
    val str = "abc"
    ActionB(str)
  }

  def ActionB(token: String) = Action {
    Ok("string is " + token)
  }
```

In this case the URL will remain ActionA

Another approach is to use a cookie

```
  def ActionA = Action {
    val str="abc"
    Redirect(controllers.routes.MyController.ActionB).withCookies(
      Cookie("token", str))
  }

  def ActionB = Action { r =>
    r.cookies.get("token") match {
      case Some(cookie) =>
        val token = cookie.value
        Ok("string is " + token)
      case _ => Unauthorized
    }
  }
```

In this case the url will change to ActionB

If you are interested in Authentication and Authorization implementations you can take a look at some of them here

- http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ModuleDirectory#Authentication-and-Authorization-module-(Scala)
- https://deadbolt-scala.readme.io/